# Strange visual artifact in Google Chrome when web page is viewed at larger scale

Tags: html, google-chrome, css

Can someone suggest why am I getting this strange visual artifact with a Google Chrome browser?

I have the following HTML for the element:

```
<div class="subMenuSection">
<div class="subMenuGenTabs">
    <a class="subMenuButtonActv" href="123.htm">
    <span id="MainContent_LabelDownloads">Downloads</span></a>
</div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.subMenuGenTabs
{
    border: none;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.subMenuSection
{
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 24px 0 20px 0;
}

a.subMenuButtonActv
{
    background: transparent url('http://i150.photobucket.com/albums/s99/dc2000_bucket/btnsmgrn-rgt-on_zpsd38b307d.png') no-repeat scroll bottom right;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS,Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    padding-right: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
a.subMenuButtonActv span {
    background: transparent url('http://i150.photobucket.com/albums/s99/dc2000_bucket/btnsmgrn-lft-on_zps2896d5d5.png') no-repeat scroll bottom left;
    display: block;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 18px;
}
a.subMenuButtonActv:hover
{
    background-position: top right;
    outline: none; /* hide dotted outline in Firefox */
}
a.subMenuButtonActv:hover span {
    background-position: top left;
}
a.subMenuButtonActv:active
{
    background-position: top right;
    color: #000000;
    outline: none; /* hide dotted outline in Firefox */
}
a.subMenuButtonActv span:active {
    color: #000000;
    background-position: top left;
}
```

That looks like this at 100% zoom:

And this is how it looks at 110% zoom in Chrome:

PS1. Note that this "vertical line" doesn't appear in IE or Firefox.

PS2. In the actual CSS the URLs for the images are defined as such:

```
background: transparent url('../Graphics/btnsmgrn-rgt-on_zpsd38b307d.png') no-repeat scroll bottom right;
```

PS3. The example above seems to work OK in JS Fiddle.

Comment: Looks like a rounding error in Chrome's scaling algorithm.

Comment: Thanks. Any way to work around it?

Answer (score 0):

Zoom is a relatively new feature in web-browsers. Your website design shouldn't depend on it. On the other hand, of course, it shouldn't be broken by it either.

One (very) quick fix could be:

```
a.submenubuttonactv span {
  ...
  position: relative;
  right: -1;
}
```

However, to make it more stable, maybe change your button design in general. You could look at other buttons on the web for inspiration, like [here](http://inspirationfeed.com/inspiration/50-examples-of-pixel-perfect-button-design/) for example.

Comment: Thanks. I kinda got it fixed by fiddling with offsets in CSS, and by moving the right side graphics more to the left. I was just curious if I did something wrong in CSS...